# Send data from servlet to jsp, display in html table.

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Since I don't have very much experience in web applications at all I've been struggling with this all day now.

I have a `index.jsp` page that sends a request to a `Servlet` that creates a very large `csv` table (5 columns, 500.000+ rows). Since the table is sorted I want to take the first 100 rows and display them in a `html` table. So the `Servlet` will redirect the request object to a `table.jsp` where the data is supposed to be displayed.

I guess I need a piece of advice on the general approach on this. There a several approaches and questions that came to my mind:

1. While creating the `csv` file, store the first 100 rows in an array of arrays and send them via request object to the `jsp` page, where they can be displayed in an `html table`.
2. Only send the path to the `csv` file and read the first 100 rows directly in the `jsp` page.
3. Is it useful to choose `json` as transfer format?
4. Is an object containing 500 Strings too much to transfer in a request object?
5. Is the request object a good practice at all to transfer data to the `jsp` page?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is the servlet getting the data to create the csv?  It sounds like this servlet is run every time the page is loaded?  Seems like a data hog to me.  If the data was in a database you could just make a call to the database and retrieve only the information you need.

Comment: I know, this would be best of course. But I have never worked with databases before and I just don't have the time right now to get into it deep enough to realize a database implementation. for now it's okay when the servlet creates the data as it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP pages are compiled into servlets by the container, so they are servlets in the end and you can use Java Code in them. So there is no need to use `JSON` as transfer format like you would do when you want to interpret your data with Javascript. JSPs are evaluated at server side.

So, I would do it like this:

- In your servlet, retreive the data
- Forward the request to the JSP (this happens on server-side; the client (browser) does not recognise this step like in a redirection)
- Build the table in the JSP (and render the response)

Servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)             
                  throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<MyObject> listData = ...; // however you get the data
    // set the attribute in the request to access it on the JSP
    request.setAttribute("listData", listData);
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext()
                               .getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/page.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP (using JSTL taglib):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!-- html, head and starting body tag ... -->
<table>
    <c:forEach var="element" items="${listData}">
        <tr>
            <td>${element.abc}</td> 
            <td>${element.def}</td> 
            <td>${element.ghi}</td>
        </tr> 
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Where `MyObject` is an object that holds instance variables `abc`, `def` and `ghi` and has getter-methods for them.

Note that you need the JSTL jar (which can be downloaded [here](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar)) in your WEB-INF/lib folder if you do not have it already.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I checked the data I put in the request object and it's correct. There's something wrong in the jsp file, because there's no table displayed. The source code looks like this: <c:forEach var="element" items="[org.sven.TableRow@339045, org.sven.TableRow@144cc2c, org.sven.TableRow@1b8790d, org.sven.TableRow@13476a, org.sven.TableRow@1b5896b]"> <tr>
               <td></td> 
               <td></td> 
               <td></td>
               <td></td> 
               <td></td>
            </tr> 
       </c:forEach>

Comment: Is this the code which is displayed in your browser? I wonder where these org.sven.TableRow@123456 are coming from...

Comment: yeah, this is how the code looks like when I view the page source.. I checked with the compiler right before sending the ArrayList<TableRow>. It's absolutely valid. Looks like it's not transferring the data correctly.

Comment: Oh, it seems like your JSTL core tags (these `<c:forEach>`) do not get interpreted by the server. You are most likely missing the taglib reference. I updated my answer with the taglib you need.

Comment: This gives me `javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089`